# Multiple File Upload Using JInput?

Tags: php, jinput, file-upload

**FORM HTML** :

```
<form name="upload" method="post" action="send.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

File #1 : <input type="file" name="one" />
File #2 : <input type="file" name="two" />
File #3 : <input type="file" name="three" />
<input type="submit" value="send">
```

**PHP CODE** :

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__);  
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
 $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$file1 = $input->files->get('one');
$file2 = $input->files->get('two');
$file3 = $input->files->get('three'); 


$filename1 = JFile::makeSafe($file1['name']); 
$filename2 = JFile::makeSafe($file2['name']);
$filename3 = JFile::makeSafe($file3['name']);

$src = $file['tmp_name'];
$dest1 = JPATH_BASE . "/screens/" . $filename1;
$dest2 = JPATH_BASE . "/screens/" . $filename2;
$dest3 = JPATH_BASE . "/screens/" . $filename3;

if (JFile::upload($src, $dest1, $dest2, $dest3)) {
echo "upload successful";
}
else
{
echo "something went wrong";
}
?>
```

Getting a blank page? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One error is `$src = $file['tmp_name'];`. `$file` isn't defined. You're should use `$file1` there.
Another thing is that JFile is one of the classes which don't autoload for some reason. So you need to either register it in the autoloader or `require_once` it.

I would do something similar to what Lodder suggested for the actual uploading part:

```
JLoader::register('JFile', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/joomla/filesystem/file.php');

$fields = array('one', 'two', 'three');

foreach ($fields as $field)
{
    $file     = $input->files->get($field);
    $src      = $file['tmp_name'];
    $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);
    $dest     = JPATH_BASE . "/screen/" . $filename;

    if (JFile::upload($src, $dest))
    {
        echo "upload successful";
    }
}
```

I would also not use a standalone PHP script to do that but use a component or com_ajax for it.

Comment: Syntax error, don't forget the missing semi colon ;)

Comment: Ouch :)
Fixed now.

Comment: worked like charm..but it echo's "upload successful" thrice? Also, if i upload two files having same name & extention, only 1 file gets uploaded? isn't there any way to auto-rename the file in that case?

Comment: This of course is only the basic process. The messages and fail handling can be improved for sure.
You should also make some sanity checks and access checks otherwise someone for sure will upload a PHP file and executes malicious code on your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can have each destination as an argument in JFile::upload. It doesn't work like that. You can use a lopp like so:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$input = $app->input;

$file1 = $input->files->get('one');
$file2 = $input->files->get('two'); 
$file3 = $input->files->get('three');   

$files = array($file1, $file2, $file3);

foreach($files as $file) {
    $filename = JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);
    $src = $file['tmp_name'];
    $dest = JPATH_BASE . "/screen/" . $filename;

    if(JFile::upload($src, $dest)) {
        echo "upload successful";
    }   
}
```

I've tested this and it works perfectly. It would probably be best you use @Bakual's code as it's cleaner and a little more simple.

Comment: it didn't work @Lodder. still getting a blank page?

Comment: ok let me test when I get into work

Comment: Probably Joomla doesn't find JFile (it doesn't autoload unfortunately). Also `$file['name'][$i]` should be `$file[$i]['name']` instead.

Comment: Funny you should say that cause I've just noticed that myself when testing

Comment: @Saibbyweb - See my updated code. tested an all working.

Comment: @Lodder - still getting a blank page buddy

Comment: Well this worked perfectly fine for me. Please turn on error reporting in the Joomla global configuration.